# Fit different Ranges in an array. The ranges must meet some criterias

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables, vlookup

I am trying to write a code to create an array from a pasted range in Excel.

The problem is that not all the cells must be fitted in the range pasted.

Out of a range 11 X 8, i want to fit in the array only the cell having a first line containing (a, b, g).

Please don't suggest to input the index columns with the numbers, since the order of the columns changes for each user.

Below an example:

Table with data

```
a         b      c          d         e      f         g    h
78,74   string  93,83   15/01/1900  98,44   60,41   59,53   45,04
71,39   string  64,66   02/04/1900  55,63   10,13   68,20   68,97
37,43   string  39,52   20/01/1900  79,25   96,74   54,68   48,02
30,27   string  64,54   12/01/1900  46,68   50,41   23,46   63,41
89,18   string  12,35   13/01/1900  31,25   33,94   4,99    26,45
13,29   string  11,98   11/01/1900  79,91   45,35   29,85   30,18
64,13   string  1,72    01/03/1900  85,61   64,36   51,88   93,35
1,80    string  73,42   06/03/1900  2,40    84,37   9,44    82,81
87,98   string  10,71   20/03/1900  99,79   6,19    95,48   75,34
35,93   string  63,43   23/03/1900  69,62   20,11   53,16   59,58
```

Filtered table, if the first cell contain a, b or g, then it belongs to the array.

```
a              b     g                  
78,73503809 string  59,53                   
71,38576766 string  68,20                   
37,42544118 string  54,68                   
30,26658463 string  23,46                   
89,18188704 string  4,99                    
13,28803884 string  29,85                   
64,13289793 string  51,88                   
1,80396732  string  9,44                    
87,98382061 string  95,48                   
35,93319354 string  53,16
```

The code should try to keep variant values since the table contains dates, numbers and words.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim l As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim CSico As Long
    Dim CTradeID As Long
    Dim CBusinessEvent As Long
    Dim CNetAmount As Long
    Dim CTradeDate As Long
    Dim CPaymentDate As Long
    Dim CMaturity As Long
    Dim CNominal As Long
    l = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    p = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To l
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Sicovam" Then CSico = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To l
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Trade ID" Then CTradeID = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To l
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Business Event" Then CBusinessEvent = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To l
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Net Amount" Then CNetAmount = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To l
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Trade Date" Then CTradeDate = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To l
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Payment Date" Then CPaymentDate = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To l
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Maturity" Then CMaturity = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To l
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Nominal" Then CNominal = i
    Next i
    Dim rng1 As Range: Set rng1 = Range(Cells(1, CTradeID), Cells(l, CTradeID))
    Dim rng2 As Range: Set rng2 = Range(Cells(1, CBusinessEvent), Cells(l, CBusinessEvent))
    Dim rng3 As Range: Set rng3 = Range(Cells(1, CNetAmount), Cells(l, CNetAmount))
    Dim rng4 As Range: Set rng4 = Range(Cells(1, CBusinessEvent), Cells(l, CBusinessEvent))
    Dim rng5 As Range: Set rng5 = Range(Cells(1, CTradeDate), Cells(l, CTradeDate))
    Dim rng6 As Range: Set rng6 = Range(Cells(1, CPaymentDate), Cells(l, CPaymentDate))
    Dim rng7 As Range: Set rng7 = Range(Cells(1, CMaturity), Cells(l, CMaturity))
    Dim rng8 As Range: Set rng8 = Range(Cells(1, CNominal), Cells(l, CNominal))
    Dim rngAll As Range: Set rngAll = Union(rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6, rng7, rng8)
    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim firstRow As Long: firstRow = 1
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = rngAll.Rows.Count
    Dim evalRows As Variant
    evalRows = Application.Evaluate("row(" & firstRow & ":" & lastRow & ")")
    myArr = Application.Index(rngAll, evalRows, Array(CTradeID, CBusinessEvent, CNetAmount, CBusinessEvent, CTradeDate, CPaymentDate, CMaturity, CNominal))
    Dim myCol As Long, myRow As Long
    For myCol = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        For myRow = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
            Debug.Print myArr(myCol, myRow)
        Next
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Range("A10:H&l+12") = myArr()
End Sub
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: unrelated, why all the repetition?  You can put more than one line inside of a single 'For..Next` loop (using 1 loop for what you're doing with 8.)  Also `Value.` default property of a cell range, so the word `.Value` is unneeded.

Comment: Replace your separate For Loops with one that uses a Select Case

Comment: You may want to seriously consider renaming variable `l` to something more descriptive. Despite the syntax highlighting, I kept reading `For i = 1 to l` as `For i = 1 to 1`. I knew that didn't make sense, but I had to read that line 3 times to figure it out. If it was, for example, `For i = 1 to lastCol`, there would be no extra mental effort to determine what you were doing.

Comment: The repetitions of the for i is a not really elegant method to index the column. By using this loop i will know the column number of the cells I want to put in the Array.